# How can I ignore missing values when plotting using subplot?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, visualization, nan

I am trying to plot my data using plt.subplots. I have three main variables, as follow:

`x = DF["Time"] y = DF["recording1"] n = DF ["recording2"]`

I am trying to plot  y over x, while label y (as a text) with n. The problem is that n has some missing values which I do not want them to appear in the figure.

1. So how can I plot the figure while ignoring the nan values?
2. How can I draw multiple lines corresponding with each row based on the value of recording1

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
ax.scatter(x, y)
plt.title("test") 
plt.xlabel("Time") 
plt.ylabel("recording1")
texts = []
for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    texts.append(ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), xytext=(x[i],y[i]-.03), 
                ha='center',
                fontsize=8))
adjust_text(texts)
groups = DF.groupby("recording2")
for name, group in groups:
    plt.plot(group.Time, group.recording1, 
             marker='o', linestyle='', markersize=6, label=name)
```